# Como obtener un pdf procesado en el server y mostrarlo en una ventana de navegador sin necesidad de descargar el archivo

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, itextsharp

Actualmente tengo un pdf tiene varias hojas en una ruta almacenada en base de datos, y lo que hago es obtener un nuevo pdf con una hoja del archivo del server y lo que requiero es mostrar ese pdf en una ventana nueva sin necesidad de descargar el archivo, lo que obtengo actualmente es la descarga del archivo:

```
//Existe el pdf en el servidor se agrega logica de negocio para retornar el traveler
                string ruta = Path.Combine(Proyecto.pathPDF, "ODT " + dtSpools.Rows[0][0].ToString() + ".pdf");
                int numeroPaginasPDF = SplitPDF.Instance.CantidadDePaginas(ruta) - int.Parse(dtSpools.Rows[0][2].ToString());                              
                Document doc = new Document();
                string nombreTemporal = "\\ODT_" + NumeroControl + ".pdf";
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
                writer.CloseStream = false;
                PdfImportedPage page = null;
                document.Open();                                   
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ruta);                    
                page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, numeroPaginasPDF);
                writer.AddPage(page);                        
                document.Close();
                reader.Close();

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ODT_" + NumeroControl + ".pdf");                    
                //Response.Buffer = true;
                //Response.OutputStream.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);
                //Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                //Response.Flush();
                //Response.Close();
                //Response.End();
                //return new FileStreamResult(Response.OutputStream, "application/pdf");                                       
                Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
```

y lo mando a ejecutar con el siguiente link:

```
<td><a href='/LinkTraveler/ObtenerPDFTraveler/?NumeroControl=@Html.DisplayTextFor(a => a.NumberControl)&ProyectoID=@Html.DisplayTextFor(b => b.ProjectID)' target="_blank">@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.NumberControl)</a></td>
```

[image: Link para obtener el PDF]

De antemano les agradecería su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solucion agregando lo siguiente en el response:

```
 Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
 Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
```